# How can I add Mageia 2 to my YUMI MultiBoot USB Drive?

Tags: boot, grub

After a bit of googling I read that YUMI can handle Mageia from the Mageia forums.
Unfortunately after trying YUMI there doesn't seem to be any support for Mageia.
I asked on the official Mageia forums and received no reply, so I thought I'd ask here!

My YUMI USB drive has:

```
Ubuntu 12.4.1 x86_64 DVD
Linux Mint 13 x86_64 DVD (Cinnamon)
Fedora 17 x86_64 Live (KDE)
```

All working correctly.

I really want to add Mageia 2 to this list! A bit unsure where to start though?

I've tried XBoot which after bringing up the boot menu, refused to load any of the distributions (halted at `cmain()` - even though they worked in VirtualBox?).

MultiSystem refuses to recognize my FAT32 formatted USB drive mounted in /media within Ubuntu.
So I'm left with YUMI and trying to get Mageia 2 working with it!

Can anybody point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 2):

Try [LiveUSB Install](http://live.learnfree.eu/) in image mode to run Mageia 2 from USB.